# New custom content type-document template changed to upload from create

Tags: content-type

I have WORD and Excel templates as custom content types in SharePoint. All was working great, when clicking on the "New Document"icon in SP 2010 you would get a drop down list of the document templates and it would show the template name CREATE, click on the template and it would open in WORD or Excel. Today they all changed to show UPLOAD. When selecting a template you get the UPLOAD DOCUMENT box to browse rather than opening the template in WORD or Excel.  How do I change it back to CREATE. [image: Capture of the drop down list when clicking on the down arrow of the NEW DOCUMENT ICON in a document library] Example:  new document titled "ITP" shows as UPLOAD and I need it to show CREATE.